# Looking for a Python script to delete AWS snapshot by giving snapshot ID or Instance name as parameter with retention date

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Hi I am looking for python script to delete snapshot by giving snapshot id or Instance name and retention period as parameter. I have the below script that deletes all of the snapshots older that the retention period set, however want to perform deletion for a specific instance name only.

```
# Delete snapshots older than retention period

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

from datetime import datetime,timedelta

def delete_snapshot(snapshot_id, reg):
    try:
        ec2resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=reg)
        snapshot = ec2resource.Snapshot(snapshot_id)
        snapshot.delete()
    except ClientError as e:
        print "Caught exception: %s" % e

    return

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    account_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    retention_days = 10
    # Get current timestamp in UTC
    now = datetime.now()

    # AWS Account ID

    # Define retention period in days

    # Create EC2 client
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

    # Get list of regions
    regions = ec2.describe_regions().get('Regions',[] )

    # Iterate over regions
    for region in regions:
        print "Checking region %s " % region['RegionName']
        reg=region['RegionName']

        # Connect to region
        ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=reg)

        # Filtering by snapshot timestamp comparison is not supported
        # So we grab all snapshot id's
        result = ec2.describe_snapshots( OwnerIds=[account_id] )

        for snapshot in result['Snapshots']:
            print "Checking snapshot %s which was created on %s" % (snapshot['SnapshotId'],snapshot['StartTime'])

            # Remove timezone info from snapshot in order for comparison to work below
            snapshot_time = snapshot['StartTime'].replace(tzinfo=None)

            # Subtract snapshot time from now returns a timedelta
            # Check if the timedelta is greater than retention days
            if (now - snapshot_time) > timedelta(retention_days):
                print "Snapshot is older than configured retention of %d days" % (retention_days)
                delete_snapshot(snapshot['SnapshotId'], reg)
            else:
                print "Snapshot is newer than configured retention of %d days so we keep it" % (retention_days)
```

Comment: Instead of writing your own code, you could use: [Automating the Amazon EBS Snapshot Lifecycle - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html)

Comment: The script would require a `describe_snapshots()` call, then use `delete_snapshot()` to delete the desired snapshots out of that list. Please edit your Question to show us the code you have written so far and what difficulty you are facing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i will update the code i have so far. I have a code that would delete all snapshots older than the retention period i set in the code. However i have a different use case where i want to delete snapshots of particular instance only. Note i have instance names or tags for each instance

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i have updated the code in my question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are asking how to identify which Amazon EC2 instance is associated with a given Snapshot.

A simple method is to **add a tag when creating the Snapshot**, with the tag containing the Instance ID and possibly even the tags from the instance. This means all relevant information would be attached to the snapshot itself.

Otherwise, you can:

- Obtain the `VolumeId` from the results of `describe_snapshots()`
- Call `describe_volumes()` passing in the `VolumeId`
- If the volume is still attached to the EC2 instance, then `Attachments.InstanceId` will provide the instance identifier

If the volume is *not* attached to an instance, this information will not be available. However, when launching an instance, tags can be propagated from the instance to the volume. This could be a good way of identifying the purpose of the volume.

You could alternatively take a different approach:

- Start with the list of Instance IDs
- For each instance:

  - Call `describe_instance()` to obtain the `VolumeId` of attached volumes
  - Call `describe_snapshots()`, passing the `VolumeId`

This will just give the snapshots for the given instance, rather than starting with the snapshots and having to discover the instance.

You could do the same thing with tags by calling `describe_instances()` for a given tag, then loop through each resulting instance.